# google drive public folder website hosting error page

Tags: google-drive-api

I have moved my small static website from Google Apps Engine to my public folder of my Google Drive.

Currently, in the event of a 404 error, I get the standard page not found, but I want my own error page displayed if possible.

Is there a way to have custom error pages?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no support for custom error pages.